# NVIDIA: “RuntimeError: No CUDA GPUs are available”

Tags: linux, drivers, cuda

I am implementing a simple algorithm with PyTorch on Ubuntu. Two times already my NVIDIA drivers got somehow corrupted, such that running an algorithm produces this traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "module.py", line 212, in <module>
    inputs_tensor = torch.tensor(inputs_train).to(device)
  File "/home/user/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/cuda/__init__.py", line 172, in _lazy_init
    torch._C._cuda_init()
RuntimeError: No CUDA GPUs are available
```

I reinstalled drivers two times, yet in a couple of reboots they get corrupted again.

```
$ nvidia-smi
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. 
Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.

$ grep "X Driver" /var/log/Xorg.0.log
[    43.342] (II) NVIDIA dlloader X Driver  440.100  Fri May 29 08:21:27 UTC 202
```